# Como subtrair duas datas usando Python?

Tags: python, datetime

Como faço para saber a diferença em dias entre duas datas usando Python?

Por exemplo; Como saber quantos dias há entre 22/11/2013 e 25/03/2014, considerando um possível ano bissexto.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

É só instanciar as duas datas como objetos `datetime.date` e subtraí-las:

```
In [1]: import datetime

In [2]: data1 = datetime.date(day=22, month=11, year=2013)

In [3]: data2 = datetime.date(day=25, month=3, year=2014)

In [4]: data2-data1
Out[4]: datetime.timedelta(123)

In [5]: diferenca = data2-data1

In [6]: diferenca.days
Out[6]: 123
```

Answer (score 8):

Tem uma outra forma também:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from datetime import datetime

def diff_days(date1, date2):
    d1 = datetime.strptime(date1, "%d-%m-%Y")
    d2 = datetime.strptime(date2, "%d-%m-%Y")
    return abs((date2 - date1).days)
```

Comment: Eu acho que essa é a mesma forma.

Comment: É exatamente a mesma forma, a diferença é que a resposta aceita inicializa as datas com `datetime.date`, enquanto essa o faz com `datetime.strptime`.

Answer (score -5):

Você também pode usar variáveis ao invés de valores fixos.

Por exemplo:

```
import datetime    
tempo = datetime.date.today()    
dia = int(input('Dia de Nascimento: '))    
mes = int(input('Mês de Nascimento: '))    
ano = int(input('Ano de nascimento: '))    
tempo2 = datetime.date(day=dia, month=mes, year=ano)    
alistamento = tempo - tempo2    
print(alistamento)
```

Ele vai te retornar a quantidade de dias. Na verdade eu quero que ele me retorne em Anos, não em dias.

Comment: Kelvin Rafael, [O Stack Overflow não é um fórum ou rede social](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2068/137387) nós somos um site de perguntas e respostas técnicas sobre programação. Seria bom você fazer o nosso [tour] para conhecer os conceitos básicos do site e ler o tópico [answer] para ter uma noção do que e como responder.  Veja também algumas orientações que vão o ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045)